# What word means “the important events in one's life”?

Tags: single-word-requests

I am looking for a single word which refers to the important events of a person's life. This might include birth, marriage, changing jobs, or anything else that the person feels is significant, but preferably when observed by looking at one's entire life.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

A common word for these events is a [milestone](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/_/dict.aspx?word=milestone):

> An important event, as in a person's career, the history of a nation, or the advancement of knowledge in a field; a turning point.

Comment: This was the first word that came to my mind, too. After I upvoted your answer, I looked up _milestone_ in the thesaurus. The only other suitable word I found there was _highlight_; the others (like _landmark_ and _benchmark_) didn't seem as well-suited for this context.

Answer (score 1):

The term used in Health and Social care for things that happen during your life is your 'life course', like the different paths you take in your life-some planned and some unplanned. Sometimes your life takes a different path than planned, which happens to us all at one point or another.

A specific event that you'd expect someone to have is a 'milestone', such as their first steps, finishing school, getting their first job, getting married, having children etc.

Comment: *Milestone* is really good, but it's already been suggested by Simchona.

Answer (score 1):

**chapter**

[dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/chapter?s=t)

> an important portion or division of anything

*The wedding opened a new chapter in my life*

---

**juncture**

[dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/juncture)

> a point of time, especially one made critical or important by a concurrence of circumstances:

*The death of Batman's parents was a critical and irreversible juncture in his life.*

---

**highlight**

[dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/highlight)

> 3. an important, conspicuous, memorable, or enjoyable event, scene, part, or the like

Answer (score -2):

I believe a possible word to describe this is monumental.

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. As the [Help Center](http://english.stackexchange.com/help) points out, we prefer answers which are descriptive and include suitable references and links. In other words, please describe *why* you believe *monumental* is particularly apt.

Comment: Seminal might work too.

Answer (score -2):

crossroads… describes a turning point in one's life.

Comment: This answer would be better if it included sourced quotes of where this word is used this way.